# Как изменить порядок атрибутов в тегах HTML? (VS Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, атрибуты

Для того чтобы атрибут **class=""** всегда был на первом месте.

В **VS Code** есть файл где хранятся все пользовательские настройки, называется **settings.json** вставляешь этот код:

```
"emmet.preferences": { "output.reverseAttributes": true },
```

и атрибут **class=""** располагается впереди других атрибутов.

Было так:

```
<img src="" alt="" class="logo__image">
```

Стало так:

```
<img class="logo__image" src="" alt="">
```

Но можно ли как то настроить этот порядок таким образом чтобы там отображались и другие атрибуты дополнительно стандартным, а конкретно мне нужно чтобы там был атрибут **width=""** и **height=""**?

```
<img class="logo__image" src="" alt="" width="" height="">
```

Comment: А какая, собственно говоря, разница?

Comment: Для удобства верстки, в некоторых тегах таких как div атрибут class ставиться вначале, а в других в конце